# Scala: Overwriting a Generic Java Method that returns null

Tags: scala

I need to override the following Java method in a Scala class:

```
public class Test<T> {
    public T test(T o, boolean x) {
        if (x) {
            return o;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

With the following approach (in Scala), the compiler complains, "Expression of type Null doesn't conform to expected type T":

```
class Test2[T] extends Test[T] {
  override def test(o: T, x: Boolean): T = {
    if (x) {
      return o
    }
    return null
  }
}
```

I've also tried to define `Option[T]` as return value, but then again, the compiler complains that the method signatures wouldn't match.

Any idea? - Thanks!

---

**Edit:**

Daniel's suggestion works for the problem as originally posted; however, my *actual* problem unfortunately still differs slightly (by having the generic type parameter in the *method*, not *class*, definition) (sorry):

Java:

```
public class Test {
    public <T> T test(T o, boolean x) {
        if (x) {
            return o;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Scala:

```
class Test2 extends Test {
  override def test[T >: Null](o: T, x: Boolean): T = {
    if (x) {
      return o
    }
    return null
  }
}
```

Compilation again fails with the error, "Expression of type Null doesn't conform to expected type T".
(I believe that's because the `override` does not cover any possibilities - i.e., something of type `Nothing` could be passed to `Test.test(..)` - well, could it? ;-) )

What does work is throwing a `RuntimeException` instead of returning `null` as Ricky suggested; nonetheless, I'd be grateful for further input.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need this:

```
class Test2[T >: Null] extends Test[T] {
```

The problem is that `Nothing` cannot be `null`, and, being the subtype of everything, it is a valid value of `T`. So you need to specify `Null` as the lower bound.

**EDIT**

Unfortunately, there's no good way around your actual problem. In this case, you'll have to write `null.asInstanceOf[T]` and leave it at that.

And, yes, you *can* call it with non-nullable types. Try this, for example:

```
object Test3 {
  val test = new Test();
  val x: Int = test.test(5, false);
}
```

Comment: That's the perfect solution for the problem as originally posted; however, I had to find out that the actual problem slightly differs. - I'll mark this as the solution if there shouldn't be a more accurate answer, but could you please look once more into the - now edited - question. - Thanks very much.

Comment: Thanks, well done. - Both solution work (the second one using `[T]` as type parameter), although I yet don't fully understand the issue ...

Comment: @robbbert Search for information on `Nothing` and `Null` to understand it better.

Answer (score 6):

`T` is unrestricted, so it can be any type including `Int`, `Double`, `Float` or other subtypes of `AnyVal` which cannot be `null`.

You probably want class `Test2[T <: AnyRef]` rather than class `Test[T]`, declaring that `T` is any type that is `AnyRef` (basically `java.lang.Object`) or any subtype thereof.

In general, try to return something more useful than null, or throw an exception.  There may be cases where you have to do it because of some third party API, but if that isn't the case, see if there's a better way. `null` doesn't appear in the method's type, whereas `Option` does, for instance.

Comment: That's what I thought, but `def z[T <: AnyRef]: T = null` still doesn't compile.

Comment: `class Test2[T <: AnyRef] extends Test[T]` should compile just fine

Comment: The `[T <: AnyRef]` does not compile; however, throwing a `RuntimeException` would work well from a practical point of view. - Moreover, I've slightly edited the original question. - If you'd have any more ideas, I'd be grateful. - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Option instead following will work:

```
class Test{
  def test[T] (value:T,flag :Boolean) :Option[T] = {
    if (flag){
      Some(value)
    }else{
      None
    }
  }
}
```

It will help to distinguish situations like `test(null,true)`  and `test(null,false)`

Comment: Thanks, but (as mentioned in the original question) that's a different method signature than the one of the overridden method.